# How to set up remote debugging for symfony2 with phpstorm and xdebug

Tags: debugging, symfony, phpstorm

**Problem:**

- I want to be able to debug my symfony2 project. I would like to be
  able to set a break point in my code, run remote debugging and be
  able to step through all the break points in my code as I interact
  with my application.

**Background information and current setup:**

- The IDE I am using is phpstorm.
- Apache and mySql server are running on my vmware player.
- Xdebug is installed on vmware player.
- I currently connect to my project through my vmware    players ip
  (i.e 172.16.48.1/app_dev.php). At this point I interact with my
  application normally and develop.

**What I have done so far**

- I followed [the tutorial](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm) but have not had any luck.
- I really confused by most of the tutorial but followed it as best as I could. I do not think the bookmarklets were working correctly when following the instructions.
- I also watched a webinar or two on remote debugging and it still was not completely clear to me what I need to do to step through my code.

**Question:**

- Can someone provide a step by step tutorial of what I need to do to
  setup remote debugging so that I can launch some remote debugging
  session through phpstorm that will open my web application and as I
  navigate through my web application my break points will be hit?

Comment: Better than just a text: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/

Comment: I will watch this, and see if it helps me. If anything it will help me frame a more intelligent question for others to help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This article as well (should be covered in that video as well): http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Comment: I attempted to follow the links your provided but still could not get it to work. The bookmarketlets in the tutorial seemed to do nothing when I followed the instructions on how to use them.

Comment: Well ... what can I say. I have no idea what exactly you did there; if debug is actually installed and configured correctly (I have no idea about your experience; I've seen many people claiming "all setup correctly" but in the it appeared opposite); the same for IDE. The reason is simple -- you have not provided any info about that. I suggest you create new thread on PhpStorm forum which is much more suitable for such cases/discussions: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/wi?view=discussions

Comment: Sorry for the late post. Egg on my face. You were right LazyOne. I went back and reviewed the setup instructions carefully it turns out the issue was with some missing settings in my php.ini to tells the debugger to talk to phpstorm. The instructions you posted were exactly was was needed to solve the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 29):

i've just finished setting up my local symfony2 app and phpstorm debugging with Chrome, here is what i've done:

1) config xdebug in php.ini on the server and restart web server (or php-fpm):

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="**location to xdebug**/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
; use port 9009 because php-fpm uses 9000 by default
xdebug.remote_port = 9009
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
```

2) install xdebug extension
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc

3) setup xdebug exteions. in chrome://extensions find Xdebug helper and click options. there select IDE key to PhpStorm. (this will essentially set xdebug.idekey to PHPSTORM for that particular session)

4) now the trickiest part, connecting from PhpStorm.
you have to setup `PHP Remote Debug` debug configuration.

1. in the toolbar, next to the debug button, you have drop down field with the first option `Edit configuration`. it opens `Run/Debug Configurations`.
2. there click the `+` button and add `PHP Remote Debug`.
3. specify your name, server and `Ide key` = `PHPSTORM`.
4. click Apply and Ok (i never know which one so i always click both, just in case)
5. now the dropdown in the toolbar will show your newly set remote server, run button (green arrow) will be disabled.
6. click `Start Listen for PHP Debug Connection`
7. click that green bug icon to start debugging
8. Debug view will open with 2 tabs: Debugger and Console (selected by default)
9. change the tab to Debugger and you will see: "Waiting for incoming connection with the ide key 'PHPSTORM'"
10. open your browser
11. navigate to your server url
12. activate Xdebug helper extension (clicking on that gray bug in the url bar) it will turn green
13. to check that everything is ok, open Chrome console, tab Resources -> Cookies -> your server. and verify that cookie XDEBUG_SESSION with value PHPSTORM was created (this is what actually activates xdebug remote debugging in php)
14. now refresh the page and quickly alt-tab back to PhpStorm (or arrange your windows so you can see PhpStorm while refreshing browser)
15. in your Debug view and Debugger console you will briefly see "Connected"

TADA!

create couple of break points in controller (dont use AppKernel.php or other symfony2 specific files as those get compiled and are not called, even in dev mode)

---

**added 5.1.2015**

official tutorial can be found here:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Profiling+PHP+applications+with+PhpStorm+and+Xdebug

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked, up to the point where I set a breakpoint. Since Symfony2 is a front controller, it doesn't know which corresponding file matches the breakpoint. 
I tried to setup path mappings, but to no avail.

[image: Invalid path mappings]

Comment: try to install `Symfony2 Plugin` it does all the mapping for you https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219