# Debug Symfony2 with XDebug and PHPStorm

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I try and try, but I can't get a proper debug configuration for Symfony2 with XDebug in PHPStorm.

I've already checked and rechecked

- [phpstorm xdebug with a symfony2 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671347/phpstorm-xdebug-with-a-symfony2-project) and
- [How to set up remote debugging for symfony2 with phpstorm and xdebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517083/how-to-set-up-remote-debugging-for-symfony2-with-phpstorm-and-xdebug)

and followed the jetbrains tutorials, but no way to make this work.

It's an rest api with Symfony2 what I am trying to debug. So far I have a Virtual Host with Apache2 which works fine in the URL

```
host: sd.lo
```

The routing prefix for the api is

```
/api/v1
```

so accessing

```
http://sd.lo/api/v1/clients
```

works fine and I receive a list of clients

**Installation**

XDebug is installed correctly as shown in my phpinfo() and with the command

In my /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini (which is correctly being loaded) i have:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php55-xdebug/2.3.3/xdebug.so"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp/xdebug/"
xdebug.profiler_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
```

And with the command

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.28/bin/php -v

PHP 5.5.28 (cli) (built: Aug 13 2015 14:02:41) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

**In PHPStorm**

I've set the PHP interpreter correctly in PHPStorm (I'm in OSX with multiple PHP versions installed. Brew installation is the one I want to use) so:

```
Path executable: /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.28/bin/php
Debugger: XDebug 2.3.3 so is correct
```

In PHPStorm Preferences > PHP > Servers I have a server

```
Name: Project.com
Host: sd.lo (root for my Virtual Host)
Port: 80
Debugger: XDebug
Use path mappings: UNCHECKED as I believe Symfony2 Plugin makes this for me
```

In Debug configurations I added a PHP Remote Debug

```
Name: ApiBundle
Server: Project.com (which host was sd.lo)
Ide Key: PHPSTORM
```

**In Chrome**

- I've installed the XDebug Helper extension and selected PHPStorm in IDE Key
- Inspecting cookies I see the cookie XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM

**And then**

- I've set a couple of breakpoints in one of my controllers
- I toggle the phone icon in PHPStorm to: Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections
- I check I have in my debug tab: Waiting for incoming connections with ide key: PHPSTORM

Could be:

- that I have xdebug.remote_host="localhost" while I'm using Virtual hosts?
- that my PHP server points to a bad URL?
- that I need to configure the mapping? How I do this for Symfony?

If I set Run > Break at first line in PHP scripts and reload the page, the script actually stops in app_dev.php:13 but nothing happens with my breakpoints.

Anyone can iluminate me?

**Edit**

Here is my phpinfo() for xdebug

```
xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.3.3
IDE Key PHPSTORM

Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
xdebug.halt_level   0   0
xdebug.idekey   PHPSTORM    PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  On  On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp/xdebug/    /tmp/xdebug/
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   no value    no value
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /var/tmp/   /var/tmp/
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

But no /tmp/xdebug file was created :S

Comment: If you Apache is in fact `localhost` (independently of your `VirtualHost` config),  I don't think you need to use `Remote Debug`. Just start `PHPStorm` debug listener. I think it's the third icon (one that looks like phone)

Comment: @JovanPerovic if I delete the remote debugger I'm not able to launch the debugger. I tried to create a PHP Web Application instead, with "/" as the start URL. Now when I click the bug icon to start debugging, it opens Chrome with a XDEBUG_SESSION_START parameter in the URL. I tried to set the Start URL directly to the URI I want to debug but nothing happens. Is maybe a different type of configuration?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. If you start debug listener, there no need to start a debugger. The cookie is everything you need (but you've set that up already). Just open you browser and navigate to your app...

Comment: Then why do we need the Chrome extension, and the IDE KEY, etc?

Comment: 1) *"path mappings: UNCHECKED as I believe Symfony2 Plugin makes this for me"* I do not think so at all. 2) Please provide `phpinfo()` output captured via browser (`php -v` is not enough as it's done via CLI and on Mac you may have a config where Apache uses separate php.ini file) -- I need header table + xdebug specific section

Comment: 3) Collect and provide xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session: `xdebug.remote_log`

Comment: @luso: That's the point - you don't. At least I don't in my setup :) However, I use bookmarklets which do practically the same - setting up the cookie with IDE key... ;)

Comment: @LazyOne I read about the mapping somewhere. If it's not true, which configurations should I use for the mapping? I've update the question to show my phpinfo(). I actually loads the xdebug.ini from a different file in conf.d but it seems to work fine

Comment: @luso Mappings are only required for remote debug (when PHP is executed on another server/VM compared to where IDE is) or local when symbolic links are used anywhere in the path (this is because xdebug works with final/resolved paths only while IDE works with project files as is). There is no universal setup for this -- it's all depends on your particular environment. Right now I suggest providing my #3 (xdebug log) -- it should say where breakpoints are set and what file is get debugged. Since you are on MacOS .. I also suggest to check path spelling (capital letters vs small)

Comment: have you exported your global var? export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM"